# Insertion Sort Error in Text or Not?

Tags: java, algorithm

I was reading through a textbook, cited below, and found the following code for insertion sort which seems flawed to me, but I wanted a second opinion before reporting it as the book has been out a while and I don't see a report yet.

Insertion sort is supposed to be O(n) on a sorted set, but this one looks like it would be O(n^2) on a sorted set as it goes through all but the first element in the outer loop, and then all the elements up to the outer loop count in the inner loop.

Would it be correct to say that the inner loop should be modified to check from the right to the left so that only the rightmost element would be compared when the input came in sorted?

```
// Sort an array using a simple insertion sort.
public void insertionSort(int[] data) {
    for (int which = 1; which < data.length; ++which) {
        int val = data[which];
        for (int i = 0; i < which; ++i) {
            if (data[i] > val) {
                System.arraycopy(data, i, data, i + 1, which - i);
                data[i] = val;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mongan, John (2012-11-14). Programming Interviews Exposed: Secrets to Landing Your Next Job (Kindle Locations 3460-3464). Wiley. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Inner loop should in the `reversed` check. Insertion sort only dealing with sorted elements of the array from the end of the sorted elements.
To get the visual and code explanation....check this http://visualgo.net/sorting.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be dome from right to left to fully utilize the sorting property of insertion sort at each iteration.

Standard pseudocode:

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)-1
    j ← i - 1
    while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
        swap A[j] and A[j-1]
        j ← j - 1
```

Loop invariant for insertion sort is:

1. At the beginning of each loop, A[0..i-1] is a sorted permutation of the first i elements of A[]
2. At the end of each loop A[0..i] is a sorted permutation of the first i+1 elements of A[].

So second loop should definitely run from right to left.